# F#: printf vs Console.WriteLine

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I am playing around in the f# interactive window and discovered that printf did not work as I expected. In the following snippet, the ReadLine executes before the first printf

```
let run () = 
    printf "What is your name?" 
    Console.Out.Flush()
    let value = System.Console.ReadLine()
    printf "Hello, %s, nice to meet you!" value

run()
```

If I change the printf to Console.WriteLine it works as expected.

```
let run () = 
    Console.Out.WriteLine "What is your name?"
    Console.Out.Flush()
    let value = System.Console.ReadLine()
    printf "Hello, %s, nice to meet you!" value

run()
```

What is going on with printf? Is there a `flush` call I can get it to print prior to readline? Is there an f# readline that I should be using?

----------------- [Edit] --------------------

After reading Fyodor Soikin's answer, I tried the following to verify. Sure enough, What was printed to the screen was `Hello` and after I entered some input, it printed `World`.

```
open System
let run () = 
    printf "Hello\n World"
    let value = System.Console.ReadLine()
    let msg = sprintf "Hello, %s, nice to meet you!" value
    printf "%s" msg
run()
```

Comment: `WriteLine` is equivalent to `printfn`, not `printf`. Perhaps your console doesn't render text until a newline is received?

Comment: Indeed, @FyodorSoikin is correct: if you change `printf` to `printfn`, the `run` function works as you'd expect. In any case, you can dispense with the `ignore` function, and you don't need to flush the console.

Comment: Yes. I have confirmed this too. I've also confirmed that it is consistent with `Console.Write` vs `Console.Writeline`. This only raises the question, why does `Console.Write` not write to the output as expected? I've even flushed the buffer.

Comment: I've removed the `|> ignore` as it was unnecessary and may be a distraction.

Comment: What console do you use? Are you running FSI in console or from Visual Studio? What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 - Visual Studio FSI. Should that make a difference? `Flush` should mean flush.

Comment: Yes, it does. And no, `Flush` is irrelevant. I've posted a summary of this conversation as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`printf` is equivalent to `Console.Write`, and `printfn` is equivalent to `Console.WriteLine`. You're comparing functions that are not equivalent.

Just replace your `printf` with `printfn`, and your example will work as expected.

---

**Why does it not work with `printf` and `Console.Write`**

This is simply the way FSI functions: it doesn't print text to the output window until your program produces a newline. There is a somewhat good motivation for it: if FSI printed out text right away, it might break your output with its own output of some intermediate information.

Calling `Console.Flush` has nothing to do with it. When your program runs in FSI, you don't actually have direct access to console, it goes through FSI's own filter. FSI does receive your input right away (i.e. there is no need to call `Flush`), it just doesn't print it out right away (see above).

If you run your program by itself, not in FSI, then your output will be rendered as you expect.